# Need to bind foreach and custom attribute to same div

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have a requirement to bind foreach and one custom attribute(data-tabs-slider-number) to same div using knockout js. I tried like below

```
  <div data-bind="foreach:{$root.EmployeeoftheMonthItems, 'data-tabs-slider-number': EmployeeoftheMonthItems().length}">
```

and it's returning error. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `attr` binding for that.

```
<div data-bind="
    foreach: $root.EmployeeoftheMonthItems,
    attr: {
        'data-tabs-slider-number': $root.EmployeeoftheMonthItems().length
    }"></div>
```